# Laravel 8 Vue 3 - Npm run hot (mix watch --hot) throwing error,possible webpack issue

Tags: laravel, webpack, vuejs3, laravel-mix

**EDIT:** Is maybe the problem with the fact that my username has spaces so webpack cli is having trouble with processing that kind of a path?

I'm trying to setup Vue 3 with my Laravel,but for some reason laravel mix or webpack is throwing me errors,tried to uninstall webpack and webpack cli and again installing it,but it didn't help.

Npm version: 6.14.6

Package.json

```
{
"private": true,
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "mix",
    "watch": "mix watch",
    "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
    "hot": "mix watch --hot",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "mix --production"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/webpack-env": "^1.16.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.6",
    "axios": "^0.21",
    "laravel-mix": "^6.0.0-beta.17",
    "laravel-mix-vue3": "^0.7.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.19",
    "postcss": "^8.1.14",
    "vue": "^3.0.6",
    "vue-loader": "^16.1.2",
    "webpack": "^5.24.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.5.0"
},
"dependencies": {}
```

Webpack.mix.js

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
require("laravel-mix-vue3");

mix.vue3("resources/js/app.js", "public/js")
.postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
    //
]);
```

Error:

```
> mix watch --hot

[webpack-cli] Failed to load 'C:\Users\PC' config
[webpack-cli] Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\PC'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\PC Master Race\Desktop\Laravel\learn-vue\vue3test\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\webpack-cli.js
- C:\Users\PC Master Race\Desktop\Laravel\learn-vue\vue3test\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\bootstrap.js
- C:\Users\PC Master Race\Desktop\Laravel\learn-vue\vue3test\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js
- C:\Users\PC Master Race\Desktop\Laravel\learn-vue\vue3test\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:841:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
    at require (C:\Users\PC Master Race\Desktop\Laravel\learn-vue\vue3test\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
    at loadConfig (C:\Users\PC Master Race\Desktop\Laravel\learn-vue\vue3test\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\webpack-cli.js:1158:31)
    at C:\Users\PC Master Race\Desktop\Laravel\learn-vue\vue3test\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\webpack-cli.js:1245:74
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at WebpackCLI.resolveConfig (C:\Users\PC Master Race\Desktop\Laravel\learn-vue\vue3test\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\webpack-cli.js:1245:32)
    at WebpackCLI.createCompiler (C:\Users\PC Master Race\Desktop\Laravel\learn-vue\vue3test\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\webpack-cli.js:1670:33)
    at Command.<anonymous> (C:\Users\PC Master Race\Desktop\Laravel\learn-vue\vue3test\node_modules\@webpack-cli\serve\lib\index.js:67:40) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\PC Master Race\\Desktop\\Laravel\\learn-vue\\vue3test\\node_modules\\webpack-cli\\lib\\webpack-cli.js',
    'C:\\Users\\PC Master Race\\Desktop\\Laravel\\learn-vue\\vue3test\\node_modules\\webpack-cli\\lib\\bootstrap.js',
    'C:\\Users\\PC Master Race\\Desktop\\Laravel\\learn-vue\\vue3test\\node_modules\\webpack-cli\\bin\\cli.js',
    'C:\\Users\\PC Master Race\\Desktop\\Laravel\\learn-vue\\vue3test\\node_modules\\webpack\\bin\\webpack.js'
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Right after days and hours of searching the entire internet, I finally found the answer.

It is to do with the way you have entered your project directory. Please see below:

I cd'd into my project folder this way

cd C:/Repo/myproject/Laravel

This gave me the above error

But when I did it this way

cd C:/repo/myproject/laravel

It worked, notice that the case of the folder names matters, it needs to match exactly what you've called the folders, its case sensitive apparently.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Alright,it seems like my **windows username caused this error**,made a new account **with no spaces in the username** and now webpack-cli is working as intended,webpack-cli probably thinks when there is a space in the path that is end of the path if i understood the error right